# Struggling to Map JSON payload to model class

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to map my incoming json payload to an arraylist of my model class.
I have a solution but its unintuitive. 
I try to do this but get compilation errors-

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ArrayList<ModelClass> = mapper.readValue(items, RoleAttribute.class);
```

FYI I am trying to save this data in a Mongo collection.

Controller-

```
@PostMapping(value="/resource", consumes="application/json")
    public Iterable<ModeClass> createResources(@RequestBody JSONObject requestBody ) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        System.out.println(requestBody.getClass());
        return serviceImpl.saveResources(requestBody);
    }
```

Model class-

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection="collection-name")
public
class ModelClass{

    @Field
    private String ID;

    @Field
    private String description;
}
```

The payload is coming in the following format-

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ID": "1",
            "description": "desc1"
        },
        {
            "ID": "2",
            "description": "desc2"
        },
        {
            "ID": "3",
            "description": "desc3"
        },
        {
            "ID": "4",
            "description": "desc4"
        }
        ....

    ]
}
```

I know I should be using jackson but I can't seem to figure this out. Do I need to change my POJO? Do I need to create custom Jackson config?

Comment: What is the payload? Also good job on formatting the code and forming the question.

Comment: Does the payload and the pojo share anything in common?

Comment: Payload is already there. Lemme fix my question

Comment: Spring should do it automatically

Comment: @the.lotuseater Those were literal compliments because you are a new user and the question was good and so was the code formatting. Yikes.

Comment: @Jason ohh.. well I try. and I apologize for the confusion hahha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with json annotation. I also notice that your values are represented as `data` in json so that also needs to be taken care of. Look at below code. That will solve your problem.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection="collection-name")
public class ModelClass{
    @Field
    @JsonProperty("ID")
    private String classID;

    @Field
    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String classDescription;

    public String getClassID() {
        return classID;
    }

    public void setClassID(String classID) {
        this.classID = classID;
    }

    public String getClassDescription() {
        return classDescription;
    }

    public void setClassDescription(String classDescription) {
        this.classDescription = classDescription;
    }
}
```

And wrapper Data class as below

```
class Data {
    ModelClass[] data;

    public ModelClass[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ModelClass[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

And json conversion code as below

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // json is your incoming json as a string. You can put inputstream also
        Data values = mapper.readValue(json, Data.class);
        System.out.println(values.getData().length);
        System.out.println(values.getData()[0].getClassID());
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need a container class for the `data` field, something like:

```
@Data
@Document(collection="collection-name")
public class DataClass{

    private List<ModelClass> data;
}
```

Doing it via Jackson should be automatic this way, in controller:

```
public Iterable<ModeClass> createResources(@RequestBody DataClass requestBody ) {
```

Comment: This is perfect. I tried doing this initially but I created a nested class which f***** things up.